# Construct http_build_query with PDO and Select

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am trying to create an http_build_query array but it is inserting some diferent characters, this is my Code:

```
function Conectar(){
    try{
        $opcoes = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8');
        $con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=*****;", "*****", "*****", $opcoes);
        $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        return $con;
    } catch (Exception $e){
        echo 'Erro: '.$e->getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}

$pdo = Conectar();

    $sql = "
    SELECT dominio 
    FROM dominios_extraidos 
    WHERE verificado='0' LIMIT 3
    ";

    $stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute();

while ($rows = $stm->fetch()) {
    $query = http_build_query(array(
        'domains' => array(
            ''.$rows['dominio'].'',
        )
    ));
    
    
    print_r($query);
    }
```

Creating this output:

```
domains%5B0%5D=0002021web.com.br%0Adomains%5B0%5D=007import.com.br%0Adomains%5B0%5D=00pet.com.br%0A
```

But this is my desire output:

```
domains%5B0%5D=0002021web.com.br&domains%5B1%5D=007import.com.br&domains%5B2%5D=00pet.com.br
```

My desire output could be generated manually using this code:

```
$query = http_build_query(array(
        'domains' => array(
            '0002021web.com.br',
            '007import.com.br',
            '00pet.com.br',
        )
    ));
    
    
    print_r($query);
```

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: You're overwriting the query each time. Build up your array first, then use http_build_query

Comment: Why do you have the `''.`? The `%0A` is a URL encoded new line which likely is coming from those appended nothingness.

Comment: Hi @user3783243 thank you for your time, do you mean this part : ''.$rows['dominio'].'' ?

Comment: Hello @aynber thanks for your time, right and must I keep printing the http_build_query inside the foreach?

Comment: Yes, `array($rows['dominio'])`, should work. You probably really want `$domains[] = $rows['dominio']`, then put that in the `http_build_query` after the loop.

Comment: No, do not print the http_build_query inside the foreach. Build up your whole array before you attempt to build the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to build up your array properly first, so that it looks like your manual array, then use http_build_query:

```
$domains = ['domains' => []];
while ($rows = $stm->fetch()) {
    $domains['domains'][] = trim($rows['dominio']);
}

$query = http_build_query($domains);
print_r($query);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, but the output keep different than my desire output, this the output I am getting from your code: domains%5B0%5D=0002021web.com.br%0A&domains%5B1%5D=007import.com.br%0A&domains%5B2%5D=00pet.com.br%0A

Comment: I've updated it to trim the database results, which should remove the linefeeds.

Answer (score 1):

Create an array of domains in the loop and then after the loop is complete pass it as a param to the `http_build_query()`.

```
while ($rows = $stm->fetch()) {
    $doms[] = trim($rows['dominio']);
}

$query = http_build_query( ['domains' => $doms] );
    
print_r($query);
```

This will produce

```
domains%5B0%5D=0002021web.com.br%0A&domains%5B1%5D=007import.com.br%0A&domains%5B2%5D=00pet.com.br%0A
```

which equates to

```
domains[0]=0002021web.com.br
&domains[1]=007import.com.br
&domains[2]=00pet.com.br
```

Comment: Hey, RiggsFolly thanks for your answer, but the output keep different than my desire output, this the output I am getting from your code: 

domains%5B0%5D=0002021web.com.br%0A&domains%5B1%5D=007import.com.br%0A&domains%5B2%5D=00pet.com.br%0A

Comment: Hmm, I must create the same output like this: domains%5B0%5D=0002021web.com.br&domains%5B1%5D=007import.com.br&domains%5B2%5D=00pet.com.br to be able to use the API, and each call gonna have 1000 domains... Could you please suggest something for me?

Comment: I think you must have a line feed in the database column?? A `trim()` should remove that [GIGO] :)

Comment: O nice point, gonna check this out, thank you soo much RiggsFolly!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

`0A` decoded is `\n` or Line Feed;
perhaps try sanitizing first with

```
$query= trim($query, "\x00..\x20\x7F");
```

this code remove ASCII character from `00` to `20` hex and `7f` hex

Comment: OP should really identify where the new line is coming from, not add a band aid to it.